# send json data to struts using angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
I am receiving data as null in my struts2 action class.
```

Following code is written on jsp page.Sending the lineDetails to the struts2 action class.
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) 
    {
          var lineDetails = {lineId:0};

```
      var data=angular.toJson(lineDetails);

 $http.post("ActionClassName",data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "failure message: " );
         });
}]);

In my action class in am accessing the data variable which is printing null
 Gson gs=new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
             System.out.println("data is:"+data);
```

Comment: checked netwok tab in chrome?

Comment: Yes i have checked it is showing data={"lineId":0} in the Request Payload